# Inline form layout broken

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an inline form where the label is on top of the input like in a bootstrap form. I have tried various options and although i have menaged to get the label on top of the input, the layout breaks after the first 2 inputs.

I have done a screenshot and would appreciate it someone could check my code and point out my error. many thanks

**BTW**:

> The form-group i am using is not to be confused with the bootstrap
>   form-group.

```css
.form-group {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  margin-top: 10px !important;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

.form-area {
  background-color: #161616;
  padding: 10px 40px 20px;
  margin: 10px 0px 50px;
  border: 1px solid #111;
}

.form-control {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(64, 64, 64, 1) 0%, rgba(33, 33, 33, 1) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #4b4b4b inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.43;
  min-height: 2.8em !important;
  padding: 0.5em 1.07em;
  border: none;
  color: #999 !important;
}

#editForm {
  display: inline;
}

.labelStyle {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.svcBorder {
  border: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 4px 8px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: dimgrey;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* For legacy WebKit based browsers */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* For legacy (Firefox <29) Gecko based browsers */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<form id="editForm" name="editForm" style="display: none;">
  <div id="message">
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="labelStyle" for="id">id</label>
    <input id="id" name="id" readonly type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="labelStyle" for="service">Service</label>
    <input id="service" name="service" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="labelStyle" for="activity">Activity</label>
    <input id="activity" name="activity" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="labelStyle" for="dept">Department</label>
    <input id="dept" name="dept" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="labelStyle" for="company">Company</label>
    <input id="company" name="company" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="labelStyle" for="user">User</label>
    <input id="user" name="user" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="labelStyle" for="item">Item</label>
    <input id="item" name="item" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="labelStyle" for="date">Date</label>
    <input id="date" name="date" type="text" value="">
  </div>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: what breaks, and what are you expecting?

Comment: Since this seems to affect the very first field in your form only, my first guess would be that the element preceding it, `<div id="message"><div class="text"></div></div>`, probably has something to do with that ... Use your browser dev tools to debug.

Comment: Why do you have `display:none` on your form?

Comment: @j08691 ooppss. forgot to remove that. Hasn't made any difference.

Comment: @CBroe Good spot. Have removed the div and layout is fine. Wanna post as answer? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot, this seems to affect the very first field in your form only - so the element preceding it,

```
<div id="message"><div class="text"></div></div>
```

likely has something to do with that ...

We didn’t see any styling for that in your code snippet, but if it has margins/paddings/borders or anything like that set, it might still influence the position of the following elements, even if it is currently “empty” (as in, no text content.)